# MDB Listener doesn't listen to hornetq

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I configured standalone hornetq and started it. Created one sender class and one MDB receiver class.
When i register my sender class with consumer class using the method,
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(listener) in the sender class itself, it works fine.
But when i deploy my MDB Receiver(.war file !)  in the jboss application server, it does not listen to the queue messages.

Sender Class:

```
**package com.mdas.sender;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.mdas.receiver.TestQueueListnerMDB;
import com.mdas.vo.JmsVO;
public class JMSSender  {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JMSSender.class);
    // *************** Connection Factory JNDI name *************************
    public String connectionFactory;
    // *************** Queue JNDI name *************************
    public  String queueName;
    protected  ConnectionFactory tconFactory;
    protected  Connection tcon;
    protected  Session session;
    protected  MessageProducer producer;
    protected  Queue queue;
    protected MessageConsumer messageConsumer;
    protected TestQueueListnerMDB listener;
    protected InitialContext ic;

    public JMSSender(InitialContext ic, String connectionFactory, String queueName){
        this.ic = ic;
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this.queueName = queueName;

    }
    public void sendJms(JmsVO jmsVO) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Message put in jms destination");
        ObjectMessage objectMessage  =  session.createObjectMessage();
        objectMessage.setObject(jmsVO);
        producer.send(objectMessage);
    }
    public void init() throws NamingException,
    JMSException
    {
        System.out.println("0");
        tconFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(connectionFactory);
        System.out.println("1");
        tcon = tconFactory.createConnection();
        System.out.println("2");
        session = tcon.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        System.out.println("3");
        queue = (Queue) ic.lookup(queueName);
        System.out.println("4");
        producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        System.out.println("5");
        /*messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        listener = new TestQueueListnerMDB();
        messageConsumer.setMessageListener(listener);*/
        tcon.start();

    }
    public void closeQueueConnections(){
        System.out.println("<<<< start closeQueueConnections >>>>>");
        try {
            producer.close();
            //messageConsumer.close();
            session.close();
            tcon.close();
            System.out.println("<<<< end closeQueueConnections successfully >>>>>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in closeQueueConnections()", e);
        }
    }
}**
```

Receiver Class:

```
package com.mdas.receiver;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;

import com.mdas.vo.JmsVO;



@MessageDriven(
        activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/TestQueue"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"), 
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "100"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "localhost"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "5455")
                })
       @TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
       @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
       @ResourceAdapter("hornetq-ra.rar")
public class TestQueueListnerMDB implements MessageListener, MessageDrivenBean{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestQueueListnerMDB.class);

        public TestQueueListnerMDB() {
            logger.info("Snmp MDB Created :: " + this);
            System.out.println("Snmp MDB Created :: " + this);
        }

         public void onMessage(Message message) {
             try
             {
            System.out.println("Entered in onMessage::: ");
            logger.info("Trap Received In Processor ::: ");

            ObjectMessage objectMessage  =  (ObjectMessage)message;
            JmsVO received = (JmsVO)objectMessage.getObject();
            System.out.println(received.getText());
            message.acknowledge();

             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 logger.error("Error in receiving alarm from queue", e);

             }finally{

             }

        }

        public void ejbRemove() throws EJBException {
            logger.info("QueueListnerMDB is being removed");
        }

        public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext messageDrivenContext) throws EJBException {

        }
}
```

Comment: Hard to help without knowing the JBoss version (or wildfly version) and HornetQ's version

Comment: I would say impossible to help without knowing the versions.. please edit your question adding the information

Comment: If you don't provide the version information.. I will flag this to be deleted. So far this question is pointless without that information (what version of HornetQ and JBoss, and what errors are you seeing)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well formulated, but let me try...

To give you a proper answer I would need more information to where is your server (is it remote), and what version you are using.

Usually all you have to do is just to specify the remote server. you have some information on the HornetQ documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/appserver-integration.html#d0e8389

If you provide me more information to what's happening (errors, version) I may try to give you a better answer.